# Maven configuration: pass file inside a classpath jar as an argument

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, aspectj-maven-plugin

Several maven plugins need/support passing a `java.io.File` as a configuration parameter, wherein we specify the relative/absolute location of the file for the plugin to locate and use.

Is there a way I can specify a property file in the plugin configuration where the file has to be found from inside a jar in the classpath? I'm particularly wanting this to know and use with the [aspectj-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/), where I can specify the [`Xlintfile`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#Xlintfile) value to be the custom [XlinkDefault.properties](https://eclipse.googlesource.com/aspectj/org.aspectj/+/b2cd5fa175facc39bd0d1af5a4646b9b39c8bcda/org.aspectj.matcher/src/org/aspectj/weaver/XlintDefault.properties) file location. The file, in my case, will be found inside a classpath jar.

I use maven-2.2.1 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not in general; there's no magic that will turn something that's not a file on disk into a `java.io.File`. Many Maven plugins (e.g., [`maven-checkstyle-plugin`'s `configLocation`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/checkstyle-mojo.html#configLocation) are designed to allow more flexible input for just these cases:

> This parameter is resolved as resource, URL, then file. If successfully resolved, the contents of the configuration is copied into the ${project.build.directory}/checkstyle-configuration.xml file before being passed to Checkstyle as a configuration.

As a workaround, if the plugin cannot be changed, [`dependency:unpack`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html) may be a way to get a classpath resource into a local file (see [Maven: extract files from jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559519/maven-extract-files-from-jar)).