# Adding content files to a Maven artifact

Tags: java, maven

I create an artifact with maven and I want to add some content files to the target consumer beside the `jar` file. (I want to add some Jenkins scripts, but I want these scripts to get updated when the consumer upgrades into newer version of the artifact).
This is similar to .net nuget, where you can add a content library to the consumer project.

According to @tashkhisi suggestion I'm trying `Maven assembly plugin`.

The project structure:

```
> pipline (folder)
>>> file1.groovy (file)
>>> file2.groovy (file)
>>> file3.groovy (file)
> src (folder)
>>> ...
> assembly (folder)
>>> distribution.xml (file)
> pom (file)
```

In the pom file:

```
...
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assembly/distribution.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>trigger-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                           <goal>single</goal>
                       </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
    </build>
```

The `assembly/distribution.xml` looes like that:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/2.4.1"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/2.4.1">
    <id>distribution</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${basedir}/pipeline</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.groovy</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>file2.groovy</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
    <files>
        <file>
            <source>pipeline/file2.groovy</source>
            <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
            <filtered>true</filtered>
        </file>
    </files>
</assembly>
```

I can see in the target folder that two `jar` files are created:

```
target/myLib-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
target/myLib-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT-distribution.jar
```

But when I try to consume it from another project the `pipeline` folder with the groovy files is not getting created...

Comment: directory is relative to pom.xml folder

Comment: @user7294900 They are in the same level...

Comment: Did you add `maven-resources-plugin`?

Comment: So are the files not inside the jar? Or do you mean something different when talking about "consuming" the artifact?

Comment: I want a folder with content to get created with these files at the consumer of the artifact. Not file inside jar.

Comment: What do you mean by "consumer"? Someone who uses your jar as dependency?

Comment: @JFabianMeier yes , this is the prupose. I want the one that uses my jar to also get some groovy files...

Answer (score 1):

In your configuration you said pipeline is beside `src` and in your pom.xml you define outputDirectory as `<outputDirectory>${basedir}/pipeline</outputDirectory>` which is exactly beside `src`(**pipeline is already there!**) so if you want to put this pipeline directory beside target jar file in `target` directory you should modify this configuration to something like this:

`<outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/pipeline</outputDirectory>`

By the way creating a zip file which contains all the thing that you need in your deployment using assembly plugin is better approach, read the following link:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

Comment: This looks promising. I'll investigate and if it will do I'll accept the answer

Comment: @Yaron I've just tried to do it using resource plugin and it works as well with some modification I edited my answer please read that again.

Comment: Hi @tashkhisi, I updated the question with maven assembly plugin. Still something not working...

Comment: lets make it clear: you want to have a zipfile which contains your target jar file and pipeline folder with its content inside it?

Comment: Yes. I don't really care if it'a a zip or not. I want the consumer to get the jar file dependency and the pipeline folder with the content inside it (I exclude one of the file but basically that's the idea) :-). Just to be sure, I need the consumer the get the dependency tree so the jar will be able to function properly...

Comment: So extract `target/myLib-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT-distribution.jar` what is in it right now?

Comment: It has the pipeline folder with 3 groovy files. When I consume the jar no pipeline folder is getting created in the consumer project.

Comment: Know you have one jar file with all its dependent resources in it, and you can also turn it into zip file. It is not your responsablity to change the project structure of consuming project you can distribute it and document how consumer project should use your distribution.

Comment: How can my consumer get this content into his project structure?

Comment: It is something that should be done in consumer application maven, Although I can't say something you want to do is the right thing there is a workaround for that read the link below they have  solved  this for another problem:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559519/maven-extract-files-from-jar/5639045

Comment: Also assembly plugin is used when you want to  deploy your jar file somewhere and run it, In this case you can use previous resource plugin I think I solved your problem with that plugin in my answer.

Comment: To my mind CI/CD and jenkins file of project should not be controlled by dependency and also it should not be included in your jar file. jenkins file and any thing that depends on CI/CD should be completely outside jar file.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

Adding something as dependency will not add or create any folders in your project.

The consumer will need to add logic to the project to extract files from the dependency and copy them to the right place (probably possible with the Maven dependency plugin).